# How to prevent non users from entering certain pages in php

Tags: php

So I'm new totally new and have done some research but still does not seem to work. I have a profile.php file where I'd want only users that are logged in to be able to enter their profiles. I'm trying to understand how sessions work but somehow the website does not acknowledge any session being run:

Auth_check.php

```
<?php

if(!isset($_SESSION["username"])){
    header("location: login.php");
} else {
    header("location: profile.php");
}
    
?>
```

profile.php

```
<?php
    require_once 'auth_check.php';
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Gaming Polls</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Titillium+Web:ital@1&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fontawesome-free-5.15.1/css/all.css">
    <title>Search</title>
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/afd6aa68df.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <?php
    include_once 'header.php';
  ?>
```

Even if I'm logged in, I still can't access profile.php. I get redirected to login.php at all times, as if theres no session being detected. In my header.php file I have this at the top:

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>
```

I want to prevent non users from accessing pages so I'd appreciate the help and any examples of how I could structure sessions, thanks!

Comment: Can you add the code in profile.php? The error should be there as it doesn't allow you to access it.

Comment: Is `header.php` being included at the beginning of every script?

Comment: in profile.php the first lines are <?php
    require_once 'auth_check.php';
?> and the auth_check file has the line that i written in the post above

Comment: Session_start() must be the first line of code in a php file, there cannot be any output before it! You call the session start at the end of the php file after tons of html output!

Comment: @pykeonly so, your auth_check *never actually issues a session_start()*?

Comment: @LSerni Problem that occurs is that the login.php gets redirected too many times so im a bit confused, i have header.php included on all pages because i want the content such as menus, logos etc to be in that place but that has then to be after the html meta tags and such

Comment: I made it work, thanks guys for clearing it out, as I've said im new!!